# Spring BOOT static resources mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I know this question is ask often, but nothing of it works for me.
I want to access the static resources, so I have a template in which I load "../resources/css/style.css".

But when I start the application the browser can not access the css file.
I am using Spring Boot 1.1.9 (also as parent in pom.xml).
My Structure is:

> pom.xml
>   src/main/java
>   src/main/resources
>   src/main/resources/database
>   src/main/resources/templates
>   src/main/resources/templates/index.html
>   src/main/resources/static
>   src/main/resources/static/resources
>   src/main/resources/static/resources/css
>   src/main/resources/static/resources/fonts
>   src/main/resources/static/resources/img
>   src/main/resources/static/resources/js

(see http://i62.tinypic.com/of84jt.png)

My Controller:

```
package prototype.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class IndexController {

  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String stdRedirect(){
    return "redirect:/index";
  }

  @RequestMapping(value="/index", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public String index(){
    return "index";
  }
}
```

Main:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Prototype {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(Prototype.class, args);
  }
}
```

I read that springboot automatic maps /static/ and /resources files...

Comment: Please post some logs and some configuration (pom.xml, application context if you have) to pastebin, and link them here.

Comment: @GaborGarami [pastebin pom.xml](http://pastebin.com/YyGW8tU7)
[Startup log](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=dnLKXrtG)

Comment: I am not a Spring Boot expert, because i use Spring framework manually, but maybe it is because you added an own Java configurator. I found this main class for using Spring boot: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.1.9.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-static/src/main/java/sample/ui/SampleWebStaticApplication.java You should extend `SpringBootServletInitializer`

Comment: You only need to extend `SpringBootServlrtInitializer` if you're building a war and deploying it to a servlet container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your index is being served from `/` – the root of the app. This means that you don't need the `../` prefix on the stylesheet's path. Try using `resources/css/style.css` instead. Alternatively you could use an absolute path (`/resources/css/style.css`), then it doesn't matter what path is serving the HTML.

Comment: Thank you!
This and a forgotten permit() in the security configuration solved it.